# Angular 4 :Passing an array element from parent to child and display value in the child html

Tags: angularjs, angular

I am developing an angular 4 application and need to pass an array NpvResults from parent component to child component. I would then need to access the array in the child component and display the value in the client of the child. As seen in the code snippet below , I would need to pass this.npvResults to the child component. How do I pass the value from parent to child and how would i bind that value on the client.

**NpvResults (Array)**

```
NpvResult = new Models.NpvResults()
                {
                    CommInsPremiumPaid = trigger2Output.NpvResults.CommIns.Where(x => x.layerId == 0).Sum(x=> x.premPaid),
                    CommInsTaxDeduction = trigger2Output.NpvResults.CommIns.Where(x => x.layerId == 0).Sum(x => x.taxDeduction),
                    CommInsNetCost = trigger2Output.NpvResults.NetCost.Where(x => x.layerId == 0).Sum(x => x.commInsNetCost),
                    SelfInsDiscountedTaxDeduction = trigger2Output.NpvResults.SelfIns.Where(x => x.layerId == 0).Sum(x => x.discountedTaxDeduction),
                    SelfInsDiscountedLossesPaid = trigger2Output.NpvResults.SelfIns.Where(x => x.layerId == 0).Sum(x => x.discountedLossesPaid),
                    SelfInsNetCost = trigger2Output.NpvResults.NetCost.Where(x => x.layerId == 0).Sum(x => x.selfInsNetCost),
                    CaptiveInsPremiumPaid = trigger2Output.NpvResults.CaptiveIns.Where(x => x.layerId == 0).Sum(x => x.premPaid),
                    CaptiveInsTaxDeduction = trigger2Output.NpvResults.CaptiveIns.Where(x => x.layerId == 0).Sum(x => x.discountedTaxDeduction),
                    CaptiveInsLoanToParent = trigger2Output.NpvResults.CaptiveIns.Where(x => x.layerId == 0).Sum(x => x.discountedLoanToParent),
                    CaptiveInsCapitalContribution = trigger2Output.NpvResults.CaptiveIns.Where(x => x.layerId == 0).Sum(x => x.discountedCapContriDistr),
                    CaptiveDividentDistribution = trigger2Output.NpvResults.CaptiveIns.Where(x => x.layerId == 0).Sum(x => x.discountedDividendDistr),
                    CaptiveInsTerminalValue = trigger2Output.NpvResults.CaptiveIns.Where(x => x.layerId == 0).Sum(x => x.discountedTerminalVal),
                    CaptiveInsNetCost = trigger2Output.NpvResults.NetCost.Where(x => x.layerId == 0).Sum(x => x.captiveInsNetCost)

                }
```

**ParentComponent**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { RunService  } from '@wtw/platform/services';
import { Base } from '@wtw/toolkit';
import * as BackendDto from '../../../api/dtos';
import * as BackendProxy from '../../../api/proxies';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-results',
  templateUrl: './results.component.html'
})
export class ResultsComponent extends  Base.ReactiveComponent implements OnInit {
 run: BackendDto.CaptivesRun;
 npvResults : BackendDto.NpvResults;


  constructor(
    private _runService: RunService,

  ) {
    super();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._subscriptions = [this._runService.activeRun.subscribe(r => {
    this.run = r.data;

       this.npvResults = this.run.strategies[0].results.npvResult;

      if (this.run.strategies) {
        if (!this.run.strategies[0].results) {
      // TODO: push this down to the strategy container and ensure params are set for the strategy id
           this._runService.executeTrigger(r.runId, r.data, {number: 2, param: ''}, r.currencyInfo).uiSignal('trigger 2').subscribe( x => this.run = x.data);
        }
      }
    })];

  }

}
```

**Child component**

```
import { Component, OnInit ,Input} from '@angular/core';
import { NpvResults } from '../../../../api/dtos';
import { BoxPlotChartComponent } from "../../../../shared/HighCharts/box-plot-chart/box-plot-chart.component";


@Component({
  selector: 'app-net-present-value-analysis',
  templateUrl: './net-present-value-analysis.component.html',
})
export class NetPresentValueAnalysisComponent implements OnInit {

  isExpanded = false;
  showTable = true;
  @Input() NpvResults: NpvResults[];

  constructor() { }



  ngOnInit() {

  }
```

**ChildComponentUi**

```
<div class="tb-row d-flex flex-row">
    <div class="tb-cell col-md-7 col-sm-6 col-6">Premium Paid</div>
    <div class="tb-cell col-sm-6 col-md-5 col-6">-142,927</div>
</div> 
 <div class="tb-row d-flex flex-row">
    <div class="tb-cell col-md-7 col-sm-6 col-6">Tax Deduction</div>
     <div class="tb-cell col-sm-6 col-md-5 col-6">57,171</div>
 </div>
  <div class="tb-row d-flex flex-row">
      <div class="tb-cell col-md-7 col-sm-6 col-6">Loan to Parent</div>
       <div class="tb-cell col-sm-6 col-md-5 col-6">0</div>
  </div> 
  <div class="tb-row d-flex flex-row"><div class="tb-cell col-md-7 col-sm-6 col-6">Capital Contribution/Distribution</div>
   <div class="tb-cell col-sm-6 col-md-5 col-6">-2500</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

In the parent component's template (that you aren't showing above), you would bind the child component's input property to the data you want to pass to it. So something like this:

```
<app-net-present-value-analysis [NpvResults] = npvResults>
</app-net-present-value-analysis>
```

I have a blog post with diagrams here: https://blogs.msmvps.com/deborahk/passing-data-to-and-raising-an-event-from-a-nested-component/

Comment: I would like to understand why do you need to bind to the parent components HTML when you want to pass the array value to child component. I thought the interaction would be between parent components -> child component -> child HTML and parent HTML won't be involved as it's just the container . Sorry for asking a very basic question as I am new to angular

Comment: The input and output properties of a child component specify how that child component can be used for binding in its parent template. The Input properties allow for property binding and the Output properties allow for event binding. You could use a service instead, but using Input and Output properties are the "best practices" way to communicate between a parent and child.

Comment: I am getting the following error Can't bind to 'NpvResults' since it isn't a known property of 'app-net-present-value-analysis'. 1. If 'app-net-present-value-analysis' is an Angular component and it has 'NpvResults' input, then verify that it is part of this module. 2. If 'app-net-present-value-analysis' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

Answer (score 0):

In the parent.component.html you can bind it with property binding like this: 
`<app-net-present-value-analysis [npvResults]="npvResults"></app-net-present-value-analysis>`

Now you can access it in the like component with the `@Input` decorator like so:
`@Input() npvResults: NpvResults[];`

In the `child component.html` you can use it in an `ngFor` to loop through the `npvResults` array like:

```
<div *ngFor="let result of npvResults">
  {{result.propertyName}}
</div>
```

Please refer to this guide to learn more about component interaction:https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: I would like to understand why do you need to bind to the parent components HTML when you want to pass the array value to child component. I thought the interaction would be between parent components -> child component -> child HTML and parent HTML won't be involved as it's just the container

Comment: That's how angular is programmed. It might be different for different implementations. But this is the easiest way to bind from parent to child. Please go through the link in my answer and you will understand.

Comment: I am getting the following error                                                            
 Can't bind to 'NpvResults' since it isn't a known property of 'app-net-present-value-analysis'.
1. If 'app-net-present-value-analysis' is an Angular component and it has 'NpvResults' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-net-present-value-analysis' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

Comment: You need to add `NetPresentValueAnalysisComponent ` component in your `app.module` `declarations` array.